# Can I define a task for Replace Operation in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I replace every `debugger;` phrase with "" in my solution some times a day. I thought it could be well if there is a way to define a task for this operation.
Do you know the solution. is there this feature?

Comment: Do you mean just find and replace?  Select one of the debugger;  Ctrl-Shift-L will select all, and delete.  Or were you looking for something else?  Do you literally replace with "" ? Two quotes?

Comment: Actually I want to do the same work you said but in all files in a project ..
Do you know any solution? I thought defining a task to find-replace all `debugger;` is a good way but I don't know How.

Comment: I have a macro solution - do you want to replace debugger; with nothing?

Comment: yes. I want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a macro extension such as [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  It will allow you to chain commands together to run with one keybinding.

In your settings.json:

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.removeDebugger",
  // "interval": 250,
  "sequence": [

    "workbench.action.findInFiles",
    // "toggleSearchRegex",  // depending if the default is regex on or off
                             // and where you want it to end up

    "search.action.refreshSearchResults",
    "workbench.action.replaceInFiles",
    "search.focus.nextInputBox",
    "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",

    "search.action.replaceAll"
  ]
},
```

This will open the "Find In Files" panel.  Then it will run the command to actually search for your chosen string across files (which is a necessary step before doing a replace). Then it will move to the "replace input box", clear its contents (since you want to replace "debugger;" with nothing) and run the replace in all files command.  VSCode will prompt you if you really want to do it.

In your keybindings.json put some keybinding of your choice, such as:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+u",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.removeDebugger" }
},
```

The only requirement is that you highlight the phrase you want to search for first - in your case `debugger;`- and then trigger it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> or whatever.

Here is a demo gif of it working - I slowed it way down so it could seen going through the steps:

[image: Demo].  The gif software is wonky on the keystrokes - it is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Actually it stops in the second input (Replace input). I uploaded an image this [link](https://imgur.com/a/ZEQmi55) to show you my thought visually. thanks my friend.

Comment: That "type" command wasn't supposed to be there - I copied the wrong thing.  Try it now.  It also needs the slight 250ms delay interval option in it apparently.

Comment: Actually I don't think it needs the delay, but do reload vscode after changing thesetting.  I edited the macro above.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now, but I have a question (or request)! can we have a command to select `debugger;` and a command for  select `Replace` option in prompt window ?! :) Actually I like to reduce steps even to one step (one shortcut). for example I can do all of these steps by `ctrl + alt + u`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ZerozAndOnes.remove-debugger-statements) for this task. It registers a command `Remove Debugger Statements` bound to `ctrl+alt+shift+d` on windows and `ctrl+cmd+shift+d` on mac to perform the required action.

Additionally, it also has [settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ZerozAndOnes.remove-debugger-statements#extension-settings) to specify the files/folders to include/exclude while performing the action.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, but there is a weakness in your extension; It doesn't remove `debugger;` when there is no space around it. for example if i write `debugger;` at the end of a line, it doesn't remove it. or if I write `constructor(){debugger;}` it doesn't remove it. but eventually your solution is very nice.

Comment: @alihasani Thanks for the feedback. Will be looking into covering those cases as soon as I get some time and will update you.

Comment: @alihasani I have updated the extension to match debugger statements with other codes and remove them specifically. Otherwise, if the debugger statement is on a separate line then it's removed with the whole line.
You can check it out and let me know if there are other possible imporvements.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Now the problem is fixed, but I see a new problem:
When `debugger;` is in a separate line, It removes with the whole line, but also the next line (the line after the line `debugger;` is on) comes up at the end of the previous line.

Comment: @alihasani Are you using version 0.0.6, as it's supposed to solve the exact problem you are mentioning. It is supposed to remove only the line having debugger; on it, not the next line, unless the next line only contains a line-feed/enter press.