# VSCode How to _enable_ Regex Find by command, rather than "toggle"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to write a macro to search for a Regex in VSCode.

Examining the different functionalities available in the editor I find toggleFindRegex, (bound to key Alt-R by default) which works well for interactive use.

However, for a macro a "toggle" won't do. The result could be "on" or "off", fifty-fifty random from the macro's point of view.

Ideally I would need an enableFindRegex function, which doesn't seem to exist, or alternatively a way for the macro to detect the current findRegex state before deciding whether to toggle it or not.

So could anybody point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: I don't think is is possible (outside of an extension) to set the findRegex state in a macro.  I have looked into that twice and came up with nothing.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305750/can-i-define-a-task-for-replace-operation-in-vscode/54320544#54320544  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281939/snippets-in-vs-code-that-use-text-found-in-the-file-with-a-regular-expression/55291542#55291542 which might be otherwise helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I feared that would be the case. I guess the question then becomes: "How can I do it from a plugin?" except I haven't dabbled in plugin creation yet and don't know enough to even ask the question properly or understand the answers. Still, any thoughts on this from people with more knowledge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a [Joyride](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=betterthantomorrow.joyride) function

```clj
(defn find-with-regex-on []
  (let [selection vscode/window.activeTextEditor.selection
        document vscode/window.activeTextEditor.document
        selectedText (.getText document selection)
        regexp-chars (js/RegExp. #"[.?+*^$\\|(){}[\]]" "g")
        newline-chars (js/RegExp. #"\n" "g")
        escapedText (-> selectedText
                        (.replace regexp-chars "\\$&")
                        (.replace newline-chars "\\n?$&"))]
    (vscode/commands.executeCommand
     "editor.actions.findWithArgs"
     #js {:isRegex true
          :searchString escapedText})))
```

And binding a keyboard shortcut to that function:

```json
    {
        "key": "cmd+ctrl+alt+f",
        "command": "joyride.runCode",
        "args": "(my-lib/find-with-regex-on)",
    },
```

Here's the full example: https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/joyride/blob/master/examples/README.md#find-in-file-with-regexp-toggled-on

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in a macro since support for its arguments has recently been added:

```
{
  "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
  "args": {

    // "findInSelection": false,
    // "isCaseSensitive": true,
    // "matchCaseOverride": 0,       // appears to not be implemented
    // "preserveCase": true,        
    // "preserveCaseOverride": 0,    // appears to not be implemented

    "isRegex": true

    // "regexOverride": 1,           // appears to not be implemented
    // "replaceString": "asdasd",
    // "searchString": "qweqwe",
    // "matchWholeWord": true,
    // "wholeWordOverride": 0        // appears to not be implemented
  }
}
```

This will open the Find Widget with the regex option chosen.  Of course, you can utilize the other args if you want - some have not been implemented and intellisense is poorly done on this command in the keybindings - I have indicated which args have not been implemented and/or the correct key names.

----- Previous answer --------------

In v1.46 is the ability to open a new search editor (not the search panel), with various arguments including whether the regex button should be on or off.

See
[SearchEditor: Open new editor with args](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95582)
.  So this works:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+g",
  "command": "search.action.openNewEditor",
  "args": {
      "query": "\\w*",
      "regexp": true,
      "includes": "${fileDirname}",  // restrict to current editor's directory
      // "includes": "${file}",      // restrict search to current file
      "showIncludesExcludes": true,
      "contextLines": 3,
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

whether the regex option was previously selected or not.   Other arguments available:

```
{
  query: string,
  includes: string,
  excludes: string,
  contextLines: number,
  wholeWord: boolean,
  caseSensitive: boolean,
  regexp: boolean,
  useIgnores: boolean,
  showIncludesExcludes: boolean,
  // triggerSearch: boolean,             // to be in v.47
  // focusResults: boolean               // to be in v.47
}
```

Prior to `triggerSearch` and `focusResults` being added to the Stable version (presumably 1.47) here is a macro that immediately runs the search and focuses the first result:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.runSearchEditorwithArguments",
    "interval": 200,   // needs a small delay so results are loaded before focusing them
    "sequence": [
      {
        "command": "search.action.openNewEditor",
        "args": {
          "query": "(TODO|NOTE|BUG):",
          "regexp": true,
          "includes": "${fileDirname}",
          "showIncludesExcludes": true,
          "contextLines": 3,
        }
      },
      "rerunSearchEditorSearch",                    // runs the search
      "search.action.focusNextSearchResult"         // focus first result
    ]
  }
]
```